# Custom style for a dynamic tab control in wpf

Tags: wpf, dynamic, binding, tabcontrol

My page contains a tab control which is dynamic. I want to populate the TabItem, TabContent along with a image in the TabItem dynamically. My Image resources are already in a ResourceDictionary, Icons.xaml.

Here is my code.

```
<TabControl x:Name="CheckoutTabControl"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Steps}"
                    BorderThickness="0"
                    Margin="10"
                    Style="{StaticResource WizardTabControlStyle}" SelectedIndex="0">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Image Source="{Binding TabImage}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TabHeader}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Frame NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" Source="{Binding TabContent}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
```

The TabControl Styles contains 3 different styles: FirstTabStyle, TabStyle and LastTabStyle. How do I bind the styles and Image Resource in the control ?

I am not able to load the styles and Images for the Items. 
My Code behind:

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
            LoadReplacementSteps();
        }

        private void LoadReplacementSteps()
        {
            List<PlacementSteps> rSteps = new List<PlacementSteps>();

            rSteps.Add(new PlacementSteps() { TabImage = "pairing", TabHeader = "Pairing", TabContent = "View/PairData.xaml" });
            rSteps.Add(new PlacementSteps() { TabImage = "write-data", TabHeader = "Write Data", TabContent = "View/WriteData.xaml" });
            rSteps.Add(new PlacementSteps() { TabImage = "steering", TabHeader = "Read Data", TabContent = "View/ReadData.xaml" });

            Steps = rSteps;


        }
```

PlacementSteps Class:

```
  public class PlacementSteps
    {
        public string TabImage { get; set; }
        public string TabHeader { get; set; }
        public string TabContent { get; set; }
    }
```

My Resouces:

```
<Canvas x:Key="steering" Width="24" Height="24">
        <Path Data="M12,2A10,10 0 0,0 2,..." />
    </Canvas>

    <Canvas x:Key="write-data" Width="24" Height="24">
        <Path Data="M17,9H7V7H17M17,13H7V11H17M14,..." />
    </Canvas>

    <Canvas x:Key="pairing" Width="24" Height="24">
        <Path Data="M37.24749,26.223C36.273693,...."/>

    </Canvas>
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What is Steps ? if just a list then you have to set your datacontext after you load the replacement steps.

Comment: Steps is the ItemSource for TabControl, I am able to bind it. The problem is, I am not able to apply the styles for dynamic tab items.

Comment: I believe you have to show your PlacementSteps class. What is TabImage? As I can see it is string, but your resources are canvas. You should atleast post a reproducable code.

Comment: The Placement Class has nothing but the 3 properties that I have used in binding.


 I know, here I have coded wrong, but That's what my question is.! How do I bind a resource in TabImage like i am able to bind the TabHeader.

Comment: @Nawed Nabi Zada  Please Check the updated  post

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that you try to bind string to your imagesource. That is not gonna work.

Then you have a convas which cannot be translated or bound to image.

I would suggest you to change your Resource to:

```
<DrawingImage x:Key="steering">
    <DrawingImage.Drawing>
        <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M12,2A10,10 0 0,0 2,..." />
    </DrawingImage.Drawing>
</DrawingImage>

<DrawingImage x:Key="write-data">
    <DrawingImage.Drawing>
        <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M17,9H7V7H17M17,13H7V11H17M14,..." />
    </DrawingImage.Drawing>
</DrawingImage>

<DrawingImage x:Key="pairing">
    <DrawingImage.Drawing>
        <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M37.24749,26.223C36.273693,...." />
    </DrawingImage.Drawing>
</DrawingImage>
```

DrawingImage is more suitable for Image.

Then you have to change your PlacementStep class to:

```
public class PlacementSteps
{
    public DrawingImage TabImage { get; set; }
    public string TabHeader { get; set; }
    public string TabContent { get; set; }
}
```

And your LoadReplacementSteps to:

```
private void LoadReplacementSteps()
    {
        List<PlacementSteps> rSteps = new List<PlacementSteps>();

        rSteps.Add(new PlacementSteps() { TabImage = (DrawingImage)FindResource("pairing"), TabHeader = "Pairing", TabContent = "View/PairData.xaml" });
        rSteps.Add(new PlacementSteps() { TabImage = (DrawingImage)FindResource("write-data"), TabHeader = "Write Data", TabContent = "View/WriteData.xaml" });
        rSteps.Add(new PlacementSteps() { TabImage = (DrawingImage)FindResource("steering"), TabHeader = "Read Data", TabContent = "View/ReadData.xaml" });

        Steps = rSteps;
    }
```

And you can control size of the image from your template:

```
<Image Source="{Binding TabImage}" Width="24" Height="24"/>
```